# Unable to connect to MongoLab from java driver

Tags: mongodb, mlab, mongo-java-driver

I have Mongolab account , there is only one user in that account.

I can connect to the DB using MongoChef tool, however when I try and connect to that DB from within Eclipse using the java driver 3.2.0 , I continuously get an authentication failure. I get the following error.I am on Java 7 .

**EDIT**
**Java Code used to connect to the MongoLab hosted MongoDB instance.**

```
    String mongoURL = new StringBuilder().append("mongodb://").append(mongoUserName).append(":").append(mongoPassword).append("@").append(mongoServer).append(":").append(mongoPort).append("/").append(dbName).toString();
    System.out.println(" The Mongo URL is " +mongoURL);
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(mongoURL);
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(uri);
```

**Exception received when trying to connect.**

```
 com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
 waiting for a server that matches
 ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
 cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
 servers=[{address=ds061974.mongolab.com:61974, type=UNKNOWN,
 state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException:
 Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null,
 userName='xxxx', source='hidden', password=<hidden>,
 mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by
 {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18:
 'Authentication failed.' on server ds061974.mongolab.com:61974. The
 full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication
 failed." }}}]
```

Comment: could you share where you create your credential?

Comment: added the java code being used to connect to the MongoDB instance in the body of the question.

Comment: where is your user located ? in the admin db or the db you are connecting to ?

Comment: @Sagar Reddy , it is in the DB I am connecting to , and I am using the same URI format as mentioned by MongoLab .

Comment: try appending `?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1` if it changes anything

Comment: Appended "?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1" but still get the same error.

Comment: please email us at support@mlab.com and we'll be happy to help you figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(mongoServer, mongoPort);
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCredential(
        mongoUserName, mongoPassword, dbName);

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(addr, Arrays.asList(credential), null);
```